# Struggling with a sql query using joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am currently developing an entity framework application in .NET and I am struggling with one query that I have to do with T-SQL.

First of all I want to show you my model from the database and know if the model is right in terms of normalization. I want to mention that I am not an expert at SQL Server database design and maybe this would be easy for the experienced but for me it is not.

The objective of the application I am currently developing is to implement an inventory control system with INS and OUTS to be able to know in which events this equipment had been used and when it was taken in and out with the precise date.

For this example I am taking only 6 tables from my database design.

I have 3 base tables and 3 auxiliary tables to relate the base tables.

**Equipo**:

```
Id | int | not null | primary key
Marca | nvarchar(max) | not null
Modelo | nvarchar(max) | not null
```

**Evento**:

```
Id | int | not null | primary key
Sede | nvarchar(max) | not null
```

**Salida**:

```
Id | int | not null | primary key
Fecha | datetime2(0) | not null
```

And the next three tables are the tables that relates the base tables.

**EventoEquipo**:

```
EventoId | int | not null | primary key (References Evento.Id)
EquipoId | int | not null | primary key (References Equipo.Id)
```

**SalidaEvento**:

```
SalidaId | int | not null | primary key (References Salida.Id)
EventoId | int | not null | (References Evento.Id)
```

**SalidaEquipo**:

```
SalidaId | int | not null | primary key (References Salida.Id)
EquipoId | int | not null | (References Equipo.Id)
```

The SQL query that I need to find is a query that allows me to get the Events from an specific Equipment with their out dates and in case there is no out registered then I should get a null in the out date.

I was able to develop this partial query:

```
DECLARE @EquipoId int
SET @EquipoId = 4

SELECT ev.Nombre 
FROM Evento ev 
INNER JOIN EventoEquipo eve ON eve.EventoId = ev.Id
INNER JOIN Equipo eq ON eq.Id = eve.EquipoId
WHERE eq.Id = @EquipoId
```

This query allows me to get the Events in which the Equipment was used but if I proceed with the same logic for the outs I only will get the events that have an out registered and I need to get all the events even if there is no out registered.

Thank you in advance!

PS: Sorry for the basic table visuals but I was unable to upload more than 2 images.

Comment: You want to use a `LEFT JOIN` (or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) for the salida tables, I believe (so left join salidaevento on the eventoid and then left join salida on the salidaid and I'm guessing you want the fecha column from that table?). You'll get `NULL` results if no records exist in the salida tables.

Comment: It's really good to google sql joins and click on images and print off the first ones you see. They are great references to visually identify what join you need

Comment: I tried with left joins but It duplicates records

Comment: If it duplicates records, then that means you have duplicate records... It's not really possible to help you out with that unless you specify what you're expecting the output to look like...

Comment: No you're wrong because there are no duplicate records. Suppose that I have one equipment with two events from which one of the events has an output registered and the other one doesn't. The desired ouptut would be the information from the event 1 and event 2 and in the case of the event 2 there would be a null date.

Comment: @GaboLarraguivel - there is nothing magical about `LEFT JOIN`s other than they return `NULL` for "missing data". They would not return duplicates any more than an `INNER JOIN` would.

Comment: From your description I assume you have only one departure date (Salida record) per Event (Evento). Why do you need SalidaEvento table as this makes it possible to have multiple departure records per event.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: As Alex mentions in his comment, the Salida table is a bit suspect.  Why a separate, related table of dates as opposed to adding dates to directly to affected records?